# How does Thanos know when Gamora and others will arrive on Knowhere?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Avengers: Infinity War* on KNOWHERE, we have seen Thanos torturing the collector to get the information about the Reality stone.

Later we get to see it's an illusion created by Thanos.

But how does he know when Gamora will arrive at Knowhere?

Comment: Presumably he hung around until he spotted their ship approaching, then began the ruse.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I remember correctly, Thor told Gamora that Thanos would go to Knowhere and Thanos kinda knew that.

Here is the conversation between Gamora and Thanos.

> **Gamora:** You knew I'd come.
>
> **Thanos:** I counted on it.

Since he counted on it, here's what might have happened.

Thanos attacks Thor's ship and spares half the people knowing that Thor will be saved by Guardians of the Galaxy. After that, Thor will tell where would Thanos go and since Gamora is looking for Thanos to kill him, she and other Guardians will go to Nowhere.

Though, this may be far-stretched, this is what Thanos might have thought and was counting on.

Now when they come, he possibly have spotted them and created the illusion. By the time they reach, Thanos has already acquired Reality Stone and destroyed the place. He was just waiting for her as she knew the location of the Soul Stone.

Comment: This is plausible.  I just watched it again and its the only thing that makes sense.

Comment: i'd also point out that in *Guardians of the Galaxy* Thanos is well aware that Gamora is against him as Thanos tells Ronan that he turned his favorite daughter against him and counted on Gamora trying to beat him to a Infinity Stone

Comment: `knowing that Thor will be saved by Guardians of the Galaxy`. Are you suggesting that Thanos is able to see into the future already at this point (before he has the Time Stone)?

Comment: @Elezar `this is what Thanos might have thought`

Comment: @AJ That's a pretty random thing to think, for no reason...

Answer (score 5):

> But how does he know when Gamora will arrive at Knowhere?

Maybe he did, maybe he didn't.  He doesn't necessarily have to know.

He's looking for the stone no one knows the location of, other than Gamora.  He could have waited there for days, or even weeks, doesn't really matter.  Once he got the reality stone from the collector, he could just run the same simulation over and over again until she got there, under the premise that she could have arrived at any point during the repeats of said simulation.

He could even have waited off to the "side" watching for her to come, while maintaining an idle simulation of the collector's area and only activated the actual simulation of himself and the collector once he saw Gamora nearby.